# Languages that optimise using logic programming

Tags: compiler-construction, language-agnostic, programming-languages

Are there any languages that perform compile-time optimisation using arbitrary logic programming?

I'm looking for an example of a language that will enable you to do something like:

- Define an arbitrary predicate, e.g. `is-idempotent?`
- Tell the compiler that `f(f(x))` is equal to `f(x)` if the `is-idempotent?` function is true for `f`
- Specify `is-idempotent?` for various functions (possibly indirectly, e.g. implied by other logic statements)
- Have the compiler perform optimisations based on the predicates / optimisations that it is aware of

Comment: I think Maxima (and Mathematica) have this ability, but it's technically not a compiled language

Comment: `MBase` framework is using an embedded Prolog for some analysis and optimisation passes.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is a [program transformation system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation).

These can let you define rules to apply to source code, e.g., algrebraic laws to optimize code.

What you will discover is that there is a variety of problems.   The first is handling scoping rules and side effects in langauges.  The second is sequencing of the transformations; the order in which they are applied often produces radically different results.